# OpenSSH 7.5p1 building: configure finds the letest version of OpenSSL libraries yet compiled with old version

Tags: openssl, openssh

After using CFLAGS configure finds the letest version but after compilation when i check ssh version it's shows the old version of SSL. Any idea why?

Comment: You should show how you configured both OpenSSL and OpenSSH. You can use `-Wl,-rpath` at compile time; or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. I don't believe the OpenSSH project has a similar page for configuring and building.

Comment: Can you show me a demo please. I'm bit lost here.

Comment: Here's an example for OS X: [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/961349/173513) Some of it probably won't apply because the recipes are for OS X. OpenSSL was already built according to [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki (including RPATHs).

Comment: I'm voting to close until you provide more information, like (1) thhe paltform you are working on, (2) how you configured OpenSSL, (3) OpenSSL's location on disk, and (4) how you configured OpenSSH. There's not much we can do without the information. Also, be careful about asking for tutorials. Stack Overflow does not provide them. Instead, you are expected to find what you need, and then ask specific questions when you encounter a particular problem.